# Finding the indices of the two items whose price adds up to a value in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to solve Google code jam questions.

> **Problem**
>
> You receive a credit C at a local store and would like to buy two
>   items. You first walk through the store and create a list L of all
>   available items. From this list you would like to buy two items that
>   add up to the entire value of the credit. The solution you provide
>   will consist of the two integers indicating the positions of the items
>   in your list (smaller number first).
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of input gives the number of cases, N. N test cases
>   follow. For each test case there will be:
>
> One line containing the value C, the amount of credit you have at the
>   store. One line containing the value I, the number of items in the
>   store. One line containing a space separated list of I integers. Each
>   integer P indicates the price of an item in the store. Each test case
>   will have exactly one solution. Output
>
> For each test case, output one line containing "Case #x: " followed by
>   the indices of the two items whose price adds up to the store credit.
>   The lower index should be output first.

I did this so far. However when I put *100 , 3 , 5 , 75 , 25* as input I get *1,22,1* as ouput since it iterates through the array for a second time. How can I get *1,2* as output?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int credit = in.nextInt();

        int number = in.nextInt();

        int[] items = new int[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            items[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++){
                if (items[i] + items[j] == credit){
                    System.out.print(i + "," + j + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like I have to say: nice question! You clearly state the objective, you post the relevant code, the current outcome and the desired one. That is exactly how good questions are supposed to look. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let the inner loop start only from `j=i+1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number - 1; i++){
     for (int j = i + 1; j < number; j++){
          if (items[i] + items[j] == credit){
               System.out.print(i + "," + j + " ");
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: @Egek92 `j= i` was there in my previous edit. I am not sure wether or not it is allowed - it basically would possibly output the same index twice, because the entry at index x would be exactly have the desired amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sorting methods along with binary search to make it faster solution. For eg:

Let's say the input prices are "100 , 3 , 5 , 75 , 25"

1) Use Quick sort to sort this price list. list will become (3,5,25,75,100)

2) Use binary search for every item to find the solution.

Comment: Thanks but question doesn't ask me to sort items, in fact 100 and 3 are not refer to items. 100 is the credit that I have and 3 is the array size.

Comment: Thats the sample input of prices which i put there.
For ur case ur second for loop must start from "i+1" instead "0"

In case if the input values becomes very large then normal method will take ages to find out the solution. thats why i said it will be faster in this way. but for smaller input values ur solution will work. just calibrate the for loops accordingly